# C# Handles Count

Tags: c#

I was looking into the possibility that one of my applications might have a memory leak, so started playing about with some very basic code samples. One I ended up with, when left over time, started to increase greatly in terms of the number of Handles (>3000). It is a very simple Console application with the code as follows:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection())
    {
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Taking out the SqlConnection call removes any Handle increase, so I am assuming it has something to do with the connection pool. But as this only runs once before basically going into a wait for input, why would the Handle count keep increasing?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you inspect the handle count?

Comment: I use Task Manger and also Process Explorer (sysinternals).

Comment: a Memory leak is caused when a program reserves memory for its own use and doesn't release on shutdown, or exceeds it's own memory quota and writes into a block being used by a different process, the operating system should prevent the second and the the framework prevents the first so unless you are using Marshal to manually allocate memory and are not cleaning up afterwards memory leaks are not likely to be the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running it on .NET 4.0, this might be the case

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/691725/sqlconnection-handle-leak-net-4-0

Comment: Thanks tia. This appears to be the issue. I changed from Framework 4.5.1 to 3.5 in the project, rebuilt, and now the Handle count is staying constant. So going by the above posted by Microsoft it is just slow to collect from the thread pool and the Handle count would eventually come down when enough activity in an application caused the gc to kick in. Still seems a strange behaviour to introduce in .Net 4.0... maybe to do with performance or something... Well at least it clears up what I am seeing. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

you will find that the majority of the object cache is composed of framework objects such as those created so you can access the config files and resources with out having to manually parse the files yourself

IIRC the default object cache is about 4000 objects.

you have to remember that just because your only creating and disposing of a single object doesn't mean that's all the frame work is doing

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get that the framework is doing a lot more in the background. But without that SqlConnection Using creation call, the application Handle count remains constant. So really trying to get to the bottom of what exactly that one call kicks off or initiates, that results in this Handle count behaviour.

Comment: if you have a look at the SQL connection class you will see that it contains other classes, such as SqlConnection,  DbProviderFactory,  IContainer. ISite,SecureString.,ConnectionState, etc as you are properly using the using command to dispose of the connection object after use then it will be picked up by the next run of the GC so there should be no leakage. you van force the GC to run with GC.Collect()

Comment: Hi MikeT, thanks again for the response. I went with tia due to pointing out the difference in behavoiur of 3.5 compared to 4.0 and above. But yes, probably forcing the GC would have brought it down. Though I know that is something that is usually not recommended. May just drop back to 3.5.

Comment: the reason its not recommended is GC is expensive and happens automatically, its been a while since i looked into the mechanics but there is a predefined memory usage level, when your cache exceeds this size the GC runs in quick mode, there is then a second level which when you exceed runs the GC is slow mode, slow mode releases more resources than quick. so as long as you aren't on a system so resource starved that the predefined usage levels are dangerously big the GC will automatically clean up before you hit problems